# Find this integral $I(x)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{y}e^{-y-\frac{x}{y}}dy$

Tags: integration

> Find this integral
>
> $$I(x)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{y}e^{-y-\dfrac{x}{y}}dy$$

I think
$$I'(x)=-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{e^{-y-\frac{x}{y}}}{y^2}dy$$
Now I have no idea of how to continue

Comment: The integral turns out to be a modified Bessel function, $I(x)=2K_0(2\sqrt{x})$.

Comment: How to find this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this integral at [DLMF : Modified Bessel function $10.32.10\;$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E10) (setting $z=2\,\sqrt{x},\; \nu=0$) :
$$K_{\nu}(z)=\frac 12\left(\frac z2\right)^{\nu}\int_0^\infty e^{\large{-t-\frac {z^2}{4t}}}\frac {dt}{t^{\nu+1}}$$
so that you should obtain $\;I(x)=2\;K_0(2\sqrt{x})\,$ as indicated by mickep.

You may rewrite it too as [$10.32.6$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E6) :
$$I(x)=2\int_0^\infty \cos(2\sqrt{x}\,\sinh(t))\,dt$$